# ElasticSearch Index Name is null

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, postman, kibana

```
System.ArgumentException: 
    Index name is null for the given type and no default index is set. 
    Map an index name using ConnectionSettings.DefaultMappingFor<TDocument>()
    or set a default index using ConnectionSettings.DefaultIndex().
```

**Error message is above!**

```cs
var url = configuration["elasticsearch:url"];
var defaultIndex = configuration["elasticsearch:index"];
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url)).DefaultMappingFor<MachineConnectionInformation>(x=> x.IndexName(defaultIndex));
                
            
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);           
client.Indices.Create("machine", index => index.Map<MachineConnectionInformation>(x => x.AutoMap()));
services.AddSingleton(client);
```

**My code in the extention is above!**

```cs
var response = _client.IndexDocument(model);  //this is where i add my model to elastic.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `configuration["elasticsearch:index"]` as your default index in your `connection setting` but you are creating index `machine`, the reason behind your error is the index value of `configuration["elasticsearch:index"]` is not an existing index in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Actually it has. I added some values in it too. But nvm, installed docker and gonna fix it today. Thanks for your answer, btw.